# Is there a way to train a CNN model, save the weights of this CNN, and then use this weights to retrain this CNN for other train data?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

Someone told me about this type of experiment.
The first step is to train a CNN and keep the weights and the second step is to use these weights to retrain this CNN, but this time to add more data to your train set (fine-tune).

I guess it's something like transfer learning but with a CNN that you train.
Is there a way to choose the weights before training a CNN and those choosen weights to be you file?

So what i have done so far is train my CNN model and save the weights to a h5 file, with the code below

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))
checkpoint_path= 'scratchmodel.best.h5'
save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'weights')
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                             save_weights_only=True,
                                             verbose=1)
 cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, 
      y_train,
      batch_size=16,           
      epochs=400,
      validation_data=(x_testcnn,y_test),
      callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

Now I want to retrain the same CNN, with the same weights,but this time with added data to the train set.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and the specific problem you are having trouble with. Please don't dump an entire problem onto other people to solve.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to make it more clear

Comment: Wouldn't this information be found in the documentation?

Comment: I haven’t found anything about it there yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to load the weights to the newly created model and then train with your new data.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model #Tensorflow 2.0

new_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
new_model = load_model(filepath, compile=False) #compile=False allows you to load saved optimizer state

new_model.fit(...) # Fit on new data, leveraging training on old data
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpfull. I would like to ask another thing about the accuracy. Could you tell me with the code below:  plt.plot(cnnhistory.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(cnnhistory.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('acc')
plt.xlabel('epoch') which model's accuracy am I plotting? Thank you a lot !

Comment: I glad you liked the answer, please upvote it or select as the answer. It looks like you are plotting the training and the validation accuracy. The validation accuracy (val_accuracy) is the better gauge of real world performance since your model didn't see that data during training.